# how can I use actionwebservice to transfer an image to the client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, client-server

Actionwebservice seems to be a generic web-service infrastructure for rails. 
Is it possible to use this gem to pass image from server to the client and how to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find a workaround my self. 
Take a image file for example, you can use send_file to send the file to the browser, or you can send out the link to the resource to the client.
Then the client could use the direct link to access the resource by a standard HTTP GET.